# Rails 3 + jQuery - Remote Forms, Not working as required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was Using JQuery Tools Validator for my remote form in rails.js i just add this condition if($('form').data('validator').checkValidity()) to check form validation if its return true than Call Remote otherwise do nothing. It was working fine in Firefox 3 but after latest version of Firefox and Chrome its skip the validation and submit form remotely.

Default this

```
$('form[data-remote]').live('submit', function (e) {
        $(this).callRemote();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

My Fix for validation

```
$('form[data-remote]').live('submit', function (e) {
 if($('form').data('validator').checkValidity())
    {
        $(this).callRemote();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is this has something to do with latest support for HTML5 Features in Browsers. if yes whats a solution of it. Urgently required help Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once my form is loaded through remote call than `$('form').attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');` attach this attribute to ignore Browser specific HTML5 validation..

```
$('form[data-remote]').live('submit', function (e) {
    if ($(this).data('validator')) 
        {
              if ($(this).data('validator').checkValidity()) 
              {
                  $(this).callRemote();
              }
        } 
        else 
        {

              $(this).callRemote();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly an answer, actually isn't an answer at all, but ...

I'm having the very same problem and worse, jqueryTools itself is having the problem. Note that [JQuery Tools Validation Demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html) is not working on FF4.

There is an open [issue in git hub jquery tools](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issuesearch?state=open&q=Firefox#issue/334)

Comment: Yep, that is it... for workaround the problem by now try to include .attr("novalidate", "novalidate") on initialization. eg $(".validationForm").validator().attr("novalidate", "novalidate")